# reverse rotation not doing what it supposed to do

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I tried to image rotation using OpenCV python I think I was able to work on forwarding rotation not sure if I'm using the correct way to rotate reverse rotation

```
    def forward_rotate(self, image, theta):
        """Computes the forward rotated image by and angle theta
                image: input image
                theta: angle to rotate the image by (in radians)
                return the rotated image"""
        center = tuple( np.array ( image.shape[1::-1 ] ) / 2 )
        rotation_matrix = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D( center, theta, 1.0 )
        image = cv2.warpAffine (image, rotation_matrix, image.shape[ 1::-1 ], flags=cv2.INTER_LINEAR)
        #return image_result(whatever produced by the calculation )
```

I got to work forward rotation but my reverse _rotation doesn't work, anyone here could me with it?

```
def reverse_rotation(self, rotated_image, theta, origin, original_shape)
```

Comment: What is the code of the inverse rotation that doesn’t work? Why do you need an inverse rotation function, can’t you just use the same rotation function with a negative angle?

Comment: can I use it? how to use negative angel ?

Comment: i'm not much familiar with opencv(image processing ) just started learning ,can you please explain how that works?

Comment: `cv2.getRotationMatrix2D( center, -theta, 1.0 )`